# Conversion with units, Java

Tags: java, units-of-measurement

I'm attempting to alter my program a bit and I'm having trouble. Basically what it does do (correctly) is that it outputs a cookie recipe based on how many cookie the user wants. It'll display the unit and how much of each ingredient the user will need for the amount of cookies he/she entered.

What I'd like to do is convert the units to an appropriate unit, if the unit exceeds half of the superior unit, needed before it displays the recipe. Example, instead of displaying 12 tablespoons of an ingredient, it'd display 0.75 cups. Example if it's over 1.5 teaspoons, convert to tablespoons.
I've gone over this many times, with friends too and I can't seem to make it work.

I'm looking for anybody who might have input to help me out.
These are the three classes I'm using:

1. My main : Not allowed to post since I don't have 10 reputation
2. Recipe class to display everything: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3d6474fc0f3345fa4a98
3. Ingredient class (Handles conversions): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/008fc9d9d4bde1c88143

Comment: Use copy & paste to insert relevant code into the question body. Linking code somewhere off-site significantly reduces your chance anybody even looks at it.

Comment: please paste in relevant code and be clear about what your question is.

Comment: Because you never call `setUnit()`, your `convertUnit()` does nothing. Some suggestions: beware of integer division, and you should take some reading on `java.util.Map` (an `EnumMap` would be suited for your ingredients quantities)

Comment: Look at a problem that uses money and returns change with bills of 1,5, or 20 dollars. it is the same problem, it is usually solved with mod (%)

Comment: How can I format the code properly? (First post)

Comment: If your code is properly formatted in your IDE, it should appear properly formatted when copy-pasted; anything *indented with >=4 spaces or a tab appears as code*. A simple way e.g. from eclipse is: open the source file, format if necessary (CTRL-A followed by CTRL-F), indent (TAB), copy (CTRL-C). Paste and there is everything properly formatted. Delete whats irrelevant to the question to make your problem clearer (e.g. import statements, irrelevant methods / method bodies).

Answer (score 0):

Check out Units of Measurement (for Java) http://unitsofmeasurement.github.io/